# How to serialize multiple query set to json Response in django rest frame work

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am getting a list of committees by user using a get method in which I am sending a user id but I am getting an error Committee object is not serialize I have serializer created but I dont't know how to serializer the queryset of that particular user id result.

below is my views.py file

```
def get(self, request, user_id):
 get_committees  = Committee.objects.filter(user=Profile.objects.get(id=user_id))
data = {
                    "status": "success",
                    "data":get_committees  
            }
 
            res = Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

below is my serializer.py

```
class MyCommitteesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        def get_queryset(self, user_id):
        my_committees = 
         Committee.objects.filter(user=Profile.objects.get(id=user_id))
        return my_committees
```

Answer (score 0):

from your code in get method

```
"data":get_committees
```

this **get_committees** is a list and you are trying to return a list but you can only return json, and so you are getting the message.

You can do this in a better way

define your serializer as -

```
class MyCommitteesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Committee
        fields = ""_all__"
```

and define your views as  -

```
class MyCommitteesView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MyCommitteesSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Committee.objects.filter(user=Profile.objects.get(id=self.request.user_id))
        return queryset
```

the serializer will take care of serialization and you can customize this according to your needs.

or else you will have to **manually** convert your get_committes into json format before returning.